# How to access values in "msg.guild.members.fetch()"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is the piece of important code -

```
const Members = msg.guild.members.fetch();
console.log(Members)
```

I want to access the variables in "Members" and also want to know what data type it is (object,array,etc.)
This is the log -

```
Promise {
  Collection [Map] {
    '518759221098053634' => GuildMember {
      guild: [Guild],
      user: [User],
      joinedTimestamp: 1595386815939,
      lastMessageID: null,
      lastMessageChannelID: null,
      premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
      deleted: false,
      _roles: [Array],
      nickname: null
    },
    '680036979106512914' => GuildMember {
      guild: [Guild],
      user: [User],
      joinedTimestamp: 1594698809775,
      lastMessageID: null,
      lastMessageChannelID: null,
      premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
      deleted: false,
      _roles: [Array]
    },
    '717347622532153396' => GuildMember {
      guild: [Guild],
      user: [User],
      joinedTimestamp: 1595919969136,
      lastMessageID: '738997364949254154',
      lastMessageChannelID: '735330127944220725',
      premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
      deleted: false,
      _roles: [Array],
      nickname: null
    },
    '730309712133881916' => GuildMember {
      guild: [Guild],
      user: [User],
      joinedTimestamp: 1594954679836,
      lastMessageID: null,
      lastMessageChannelID: null,
      premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
      deleted: false,
      _roles: [Array],
      nickname: null
    },
    '730624908748521613' => GuildMember {
      guild: [Guild],
      user: [User],
      joinedTimestamp: 1594698780260,
      lastMessageID: null,
      lastMessageChannelID: null,
      premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
      deleted: false,
      _roles: [Array],
      nickname: null
    },
    '738658236957458472' => GuildMember {
      guild: [Guild],
      user: [ClientUser],
      joinedTimestamp: 1596183671593,
      lastMessageID: '738997347387965531',
      lastMessageChannelID: '735330127944220725',
      premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
      deleted: false,
      _roles: [Array],
      nickname: null
    }
  }
}
```

How do you store, for example, the user ID in this line:

```
'518759221098053634' => GuildMember {
```

I think there is one duplicate of this question, but i think the solutions there are outdated or for a different language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild).[members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager).[fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) is a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that will return:

- A [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) if you provide a [UserResolvable](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/UserResolvable) as the first parameter.
- A [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) containing all the members in the guild if you don't provide anything as the first parameter.

---

```js
message.guild.members.fetch("UserID").then(member => {
    // This will return a single GuildMember object, if found.
    console.log(`Found ${member.user.tag}. They are ${member.presence.status}.`);
}).catch(e => console.log("Couldn't fetch the member."));
```

```js
// This will return a Collection containing all members in the Guild. 
message.guild.members.fetch().then(members => {
    // To store the user id(s) you can map the Collection by ID:
    const IDs = members.map(user => user.id);
        // --> ["UserID", "UserID", "UserID", "UserID"]

    // To store certain id(s) you can use the filter method of Collection:

    const OnlineMembers = members.filter(member => member.presence.status == "online");
}).catch(e => console.log("Couldn't fetch members."));
```

---

References:

- [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection)
- [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)
- [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild)
- [GuildMemberManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager)
- [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Wait now it says map() is not defined.

Comment: `map()` only works on `Collection` / `Array`. If you provided a `UserResolvable` to the `fetch()` method, it will return a `GuildMember`, not a `Collection`; and therefore you cannot use `fetch()`.

Comment: I didn't provide any arguments to fetch() though.

Comment: Aha i found the problem and your code works fine now.